# Использовать Websocket в контроллере asp.net core mvc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, websocket, asp.net-core

Как использовать websocket в контроллерах asp.net core mvc?

Я хочу например в реальном времени отображать изменения данных о пользователе (его userName и Email).В интернете нашел много инструкций как реализовать websocket через создания Middleware. Мне бы хотелось использовать привычные мне контролеры, где есть атрибуты вроде `[Authorize]`, получение сервисов через Dependency Injection и тд.

Comment: Про SignalR слышал?

Comment: @Alex78191 он же в альфе, не думаю что его использовать хорошая идея

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35554128/opening-a-websocket-channel-inside-mvc-controller

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25668398/using-websockets-with-asp-net-web-api

Comment: Можно сделать свой IActionResult где зависнуть в ExecuteResultAsync и в это время слать в сокет сколько угодно. Я так сделал имплементацию server sent events без middleware по той же причине - контроллер должен решать разрешено ли пользователю подключение и куда.

Answer (score 2):

Я тоже задался этой идеей и реализовал её на базе основной документации по Middleware.

```
[Route("ws/[controller]/[action]")]
[Authorize(Roles = TechnicalRoles.HopProgram)]
public class HopController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public ChopController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Нужно для коннекта клиента
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task Connect()
    {
        if (HttpContext.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
        {
            WebSocket webSocket = await HttpContext.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
            await Echo(HttpContext, webSocket);
        }
        else
        {
            HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 400;
        }
    }

    // Тест возврата полученных сообщений
    private async Task Echo(HttpContext context, WebSocket webSocket)
    {
        var buffer = new byte[1024 * 4];
        WebSocketReceiveResult result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer),
            CancellationToken.None);
        while (!result.CloseStatus.HasValue)
        {
            await webSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer, 0, result.Count),
                result.MessageType,
                result.EndOfMessage,
                CancellationToken.None);

            result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer),
                CancellationToken.None);
        }
        await webSocket.CloseAsync(result.CloseStatus.Value,
            result.CloseStatusDescription,
            CancellationToken.None);
    }
}
```

Подключаемся к этому добру по адресу ws://localhost:порт/ws/hop/connect